# The Earth's Core

Tags: electromagnetism, rotational-dynamics, superconductivity, geophysics

4 questions about the Earth's core

1. Does the earths core rotate differentially to the earths crust or surface? and what is the differential rotation, if any?
2. Due to the increased pressure (of 3.6GPA) at the earth's core  and the high temperatures can it be assumed that the core is a superheated liquid despite the fact that it is thought to be a ferro/nickel build-up?
3. Does the increased pressure and temperature at the earth's core allow for superconductivity to occur within earth's global system i.e  Is it acting as  sustainable  and continuous power source ?
4. What level of electro-magnetic activity occurs at the earths core  and where can I find more information on this?

Comment: Replace questions with statements and consider this as a theory.

Comment: see this for 1. https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2009/12/091223222743.htm . the rest are matters for research